# How to submit a text to a button and when pressed the button it will show the text on another page using bloc in flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

How to submit a text to a button and when pressed the button it will show the text on another page using bloc in flutter.

Comment: previous issue is solved.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: "initialText");` and give it to `TextField` like that `TextField(controller: controlller)`. Now you can get textfield text anytime with `controller.text`